# How to add specific piece of code in each method of class

Tags: ruby, class, oop, object

I have a class named `Some`. Each method of `Some` returns a string.
But I want all methods to `return self`. It's just a matter of adding `return self` at the end, but is there any simpler and smarter way?
I cannot tamper with the original class, so please answer with that in consideration.

I don't know what to try. Please help.

Comment: I am extremely curious about the circumstances that motivated this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add only `self` as a last statement to each method. No need to write `return self`,only `self` is sufficient.

**Update**

As per your last edit,I think you can use [**`Method#receiver`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-receiver),if you don't want to open your class again.

```
class Demo
  def foo
    # code
  end
end

bar = Demo.new # => #<Demo:0x115c7d0>
bar.method(:foo).receiver # => #<Demo:0x115c7d0>
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe  `return self` is  the  simplest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

if You wan't to be able to chain methods and not call receiver between calls You can try to wrap Your object with something like this:

```rb
class Foo

  def foo1_method
    puts 'foo1_method'
  end

  def foo2_method
    puts 'foo2_method'
  end

end

class Chainable
  attr_reader :receiver

  def initialize(obj)
    @receiver = obj
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &blk)
    if @receiver.respond_to?(method)
      @receiver.send(method, *args, &blk)
      self
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to?(method)
    if @receiver.respond_to? method
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end

end

obj = Foo.new
chainable = Chainable.new obj
chainable.foo1_method.foo2_method
```

if You want to get back original object You can get it like this

```
chainable.receiver
```